# An + Akkusativ statt Dativ

Tags: preposition, dative, objects

Wie auf Englisch mit dem bekannten "dative shift" (*I gave **John** a point ⟷ I gave a point **to** John*) gibt es im Deutschen auch einige Verben (vor allem Verben des Gebens), die neben dem Akkusativobjekt entweder mit einem Dativobjekt oder mit einem Präpositionalobjekt mit der Präposition "*an*" fungieren können.

Einige Beispiele solcher Verben sind:

| Dativ | *»an«* + Akkusaitv |
| --- | --- |
| Ich schicke **ihm** das Packet. | Ich schicke das Packet **an ihn.** |
| Wir verkaufen **unserm Nachbarn** das rote Auto. | Wir verkaufen das rote Auto **an unseren Nachbarn.** |
| Ich schreibe **meiner Mutter** einen Brief. | Ich schreibe einen Brief **an meine Mutter.** |

Meine erste Frage wäre also: Sind diese Paare komplett bedeutungsgleich oder implizieren sie einen Bedeutungswandel? (zB. einen Standortwechsel?)

Vor Kurzem habe ich von PayPal eine E-Mail bekommen, auf der Folgendes zu lesen ist:

> Empfehlen Sie uns **an Freunde**, die noch kein PayPal-Konto haben.

Dann bekam ich eine zweite Frage: Wie korrekt ist das eigentlich? Sofern ich weiß, funktioniert das Verb *empfehlen* immer mit Dativ (***jemandem** etwas empfehlen*). Die Konfiguration mit "*an*" kommt mir sehr merkwürdig vor.

Die dritte Frage wäre also: Dürfen auch andere gebräuchliche Verben wie zB *geben*, *mitteilen*, *erzählen* auch ein Präpositionalobjekt mit *an* statt Dativ mit sich tragen? (zB: *Ich gebe / erzähle / teile es **an dich** (mit)* statt *ich gebe / erzähle / teile es **dir** (mit)*?)

Answer (score 3):

1. Diese Beispiele sind bedeutungsgleich, soweit das überhaupt für strukturell verschiedene Konstuktionen möglich ist. ("schreibe einen Brief an meine Mutter" erlaubt zum Beispiel eine alternative Lesart, in der die Präposition zum Nomen "Brief" gehört statt zum Verb, was mit dem Dativ nicht möglich ist, und diese Mehrdeutigkeit muss irgend eine geringfügige Auswirkung auf das Verständnis haben - nur eben keine grosse.)
2. "etw. an jmd. empfehlen" ist ungewöhnlich, allerdings sofort verständlich - vermutlich eben wegen der parallelen Konstruktion zu "geben", "schicken" etc. (Gebräuchlicher, obwohl veraltet,  wäre ironischerweise die umgekehrte Konstruktion: jmd. etw. *anempfehlen*).
3. Diese drei Verben wären noch ungewohnlicher in einer Konstruktion mit "an". Beim ersten gibt es immerhin die Variante "etw. an jmd. *weiter*geben@, die verbreitet ist (ohne dass so recht klar ist, warum).

Comment: '"schreibe einen Brief an meine Mutter" erlaubt zum Beispiel eine alternative Lesart, in der die Präposition zum Nomen "Brief" gehört statt zum Verb' Häh???

Comment: @Roland Hier wird wohl gemeint, dass der Satz sich auf zwei verschiedene Weisen verstehen lässt und zwar "[ich schreibe][einen Brief][an meine Mutter]" und "[ich schreibe][einen Brief an meine Mutter]".

Comment: @SehrSowie Danke. ("Ich schreibe an meine Mutter." erscheint mir mindestens stilistisch verschwurbelt, möglicherweise veraltet.)

Comment: @Roland: mir ist nicht klar, was daran "verschwurbelt" oder "veraltet" sein soll. Hast du dafür irgendeine Quelle, einen Beleg oder zumindest ein Indiz? Und wie muß die dazugehörige Frage lauten: "*An wen schreibst du Briefe*" oder "*Wem schreibst du Briefe*"? Letzteres ist zumindest doppeldeutig und könnte auch "*Für wen schreibst du Briefe*" bedeuten.

Answer (score 1):

Im Deutschen gibt es den freien Dativ, den man beliebigen Verben hinzufügen kann um den Nutznießer, den Geschädigten oder sonst einen Betroffenen zu nennen, den das Verb eigentlich gar nicht benötigt.

> Ich koche warme Suppe.
> Ich koche **meiner Frau** warme Suppe.

Das freie Dativobjekt *»meiner Frau«* gibt an, wer von der Aktion einen Nutzen hat. Dasselbe gilt im Grunde genommen auch für das Verb *»schreiben«:*

> Ich schreibe einen Brief.
> Ich schreibe **meiner Mutter** einen Brief.

Das Verb *»schreiben«* sieht eigentlich nicht vor, dass es zusammen mit einem Empfänger verwendet wird, aber man kann einen freien Dativ hinzufügen, der eigentlich den Begünstigten der Handlung ausdrückt, hier aber auch als Empfänger des Briefes verstanden werden kann.

Alternative Interpretation: Meine Mutter kann (aufgrund einer Erkrankung) nicht selbst schreiben, möchte aber einen Brief schreiben (z.B. an das Finanzamt). Ich helfe ihr und schreibe den Brief für sie.

Auch das Verb *»verkaufen«* kommt ohne den Käufer aus:

> Wir verkaufen das rote Auto.
> Wir verkaufen **unserm Nachbarn** das rote Auto.

Auch hier muss *unser Nachbar* gar nicht der Käufer sein. Es könnte der Verkäufer sein, der mit der Abwicklung des Verkaufs unerfahren ist, und uns gebeten hat, für ihn den Verkauf abzuwickeln.

Die Verben, die semantisch mehr oder weniger mit *»geben«* verwandt sind (*bringen, bieten, reichen, schicken ...*) kommen nur dann ohne Nennung des Empfängers aus, wenn die Handlung allgemein gehalten ist, aber das ist eben durchaus möglich, daher ist auch hier das Dativobjekt ein freies Objekt:

> Frau Schmidt reichte belegte Brote.
> Frau Schmidt reichte **ihren Gästen** belegte Brote.
>
> Herr Huber schickt rote Rosen.
> Herr Huber schickt **seiner Frau** rote Rosen.

Wie gesagt benennt so ein freies Dativobjekt jene Person oder jenes Ding, dass von der Handlung betroffen ist. Es benennt aber nicht explizit einen Empfänger. Das leistet aber ein Präpositionalobjekt mit der Präposition *»an«* und dem Empfänger im Akkusativ, denn diese Kombination kennzeichnet durch den Akkusativ eine Bewegung, die wegen der Präposition *»an«* am genannten Punkt endet:

> freies Dativobjekt = Nutznießer: Ich schreibe **meiner Mutter** einen Brief.
> an + Akkusativ = Empfänger: Ich schreibe einen Brief **an meine Mutter.**
>
> freies Dativobjekt = Nutznießer: Wir verkaufen **unserm Nachbarn** das rote Auto.
> an + Akkusativ = Empfänger: Wir verkaufen das rote Auto **an unseren Nachbarn.**
>
> freies Dativobjekt = Nutznießer: Herr Huber schickt **seiner Frau** rote Rosen.
> an + Akkusativ = Empfänger: Herr Huber schickt rote Rosen **an seine Frau.**

Aber nicht immer macht es Sinn, den Nutznießer als Empfänger zu interpretieren, und in solchen Fällen kann die Konstruktion *an + Akkusativ* nicht verwendet werden:

> Korrekt: freies Dativobjekt = Nutznießer: Ich koche **meiner Frau** warme Suppe.
> Unsinnig und daher falsch: an + Akkusativ = Empfänger: Ich koche warme Suppe **an meine Frau.**
>
> Korrekt: freies Dativobjekt = Nutznießer: Ich erzähle **dir** eine Geschichte.
> Unsinnig und daher falsch: an + Akkusativ = Empfänger: Ich erzähle eine Geschichte **an dich.**

Was für *kochen* und *erzählen* gilt, würde ich auch für *empfehlen* meinen:

> Korrekt: freies Dativobjekt = Nutznießer: Ich empfehle **meinen Freunden** diesen Dienstleiter.
> Zumindest stilistisch schlecht: an + Akkusativ = Empfänger: Ich empfehle diesen diesen Dienstleister **an meine Freunde.**
>
> Korrekt: freies Dativobjekt = Nutznießer: Empfehlen Sie uns **ihren Freunden.**
> Zumindest stilistisch schlecht: an + Akkusativ = Empfänger: Empfehlen Sie uns **an ihre Freunde.**